# JS functions in object disappears

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, object, local-storage

When I initially call this function:

```
var session = function(){
    console.error(service.get());
    if(service.get().session === undefined){
        $localStorage.user.session = {
            timeLeft: 0,  //  Time left until a user session ends (in minutes).
            start: function(timeLeft) {
                $localStorage.user.session.timeLeft = timeLeft;
                $localStorage.user.session.interval;
            },
            stop: function(){
                $interval.cancel($localStorage.user.session.interval);
            },
            interval: $interval(function () {
                $localStorage.user.session.timeLeft -= 1;

                if($localStorage.user.session.timeLeft <= 0){
                    $state.go('signin');
                }
            }, 0.125 * 60000)
        };
    }

    return $localStorage.user.session;
};
```

from

```
function sessionRestart(){
    session();
};
sessionRestart();
```

It creates the `session` object with all its variables, but when I reload the page it doesn't populate the variables which are functions. How can I fix that?

**EDIT**
The application is `AngularJS` and I'm using `ngStorage` for the `$localStorage`, and the code is meant for a user session which can be found in a `factory` in my application.

Comment: I don't know how it works in angularjs, but in `localstorage` you only can store plain text data, so your JSON or Object needs to be stringified.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude OP is not using localStorage directly, so it's fine.

Comment: @dfsq ok, I said `I don't know how it works in angularjs` because that. But if it's ok, ok it is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MarcosPérezGude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5035890/marcos-p%C3%A9rez-gude) made me think of a solution to the problem. Which were to move the `$interval` outside of the `$localStorage` which fixed my problem. Not sure why it wouldn't work thou.

The code now looks like this:

```
var session,
    startSession: function(timeLeft) {
        if($localStorage.user.session === undefined){
            if(timeLeft === undefined){
                timeLeft = 0;
            }

            $localStorage.user.session = {
                timeLeft: timeLeft
            };
        }

        if (session === undefined) {
            session = $interval(function () {
                $localStorage.user.session.timeLeft -= 1;

                if($localStorage.user.session.timeLeft === undefined){
                    service.stopSession();
                }

                if($localStorage.user.session.timeLeft <= 0){
                    $state.go('signin');
                }
            }, 1 * 60000);  //  Time in milliseconds. Minutes * milliseconds = total milliseconds before the interval repeats.
        }
    },
    stopSession: function() {
        $interval.cancel(session);
        session = undefined;
    };
```